# How to set different row height in UITableView programatically?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to display different row height in my `tableView`. I am using this code:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            return 50
        } else {
            return 120
        }
    }
```

But I have height=50 in all my cells. I start looking for the problem and use this code to check what is wrong.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(format: "cell", indexPath.row), for: indexPath) as! ShopTableViewCell
        
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.viewInCollection.backgroundColor = .blue
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            cell.viewInCollection.backgroundColor = .gray
        } else {
            cell.viewInCollection.backgroundColor = .red
        }

    return cell
}
```

In this case my cells show only blue color. How to fix it?

UITableVIewCellClass:

```
class ShopTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    let viewInCollection = UIView()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        contentView.addSubview(viewInCollection)
       viewInCollection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let margins = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        viewInCollection.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        viewInCollection.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        viewInCollection.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        viewInCollection.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true 

       
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
        
}
```

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: How are you setting your cell up? Can you add the `UITableViewCell` code.

Comment: also, as an aside, there is no point using `String(format: cell, index path.row)` for the ID when you are not using the argument in the string. Set a static string on their cell as the identifier and use that.  (And I assume not returning cell in `cellForRowAt` is just a copy/paste error?!)

Comment: @flanker I updated my question. Also now I have cell identifier `cell` in my `TableViewController` in storyboard

Comment: screenshot please...

Comment: You have `cell.viewInCollection` but I don't see `viewInCollection` inside your `ShoppingCell` class

Comment: @FahimParkar sorry copy/paste error edited question

Comment: @User : Can you make sample project and upload somewhere and share link to check further...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have **specific view with dynamic height** in your tableView Cell, you can add a stackView to nib file as your dynamic view and you can add to any view to your stackView programatically.
Example:
Use below code in setup tableView Cell

```
func setupTableViewCell() {
    // when reload tableView, you should first remove all subviews.
    yourStackView.removeAllArrangedSubviews()

    let customView = CustomView()
    // custom setup funcs for CustomView...
    // it can be any UIComponent

    yourStackView.addArrangedSubview(customView)
}
```

this methods makes your cell dynamic height. and also you should add UITableViewDelegate func **heightForFooterInSection**.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

here you have set **numberOfSections** in tableView as 1 and **numberOfRowsInSection** as 3. so you have to access each different table view cell using **indexPath.item**  instead of **indexPath.row**

here is the code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        if indexPath.item == 0 {
            return 50
        } else {
            return 120
        }
    }
```

Comment: `item` is meant for use with `UICollectionView`. `row` is meant for use with `UITableView`. Functionally they are the same so your answer doesn't actually change anything. The OP's use of `indexPath.row` is correct. BTW - the distinction between `item` and `row` is better documented in `NSIndexPath` than `IndexPath`.